# Can someone explain to me the problem with my sum in R

Tags: r, sum

for a given matrix F I want to calculate the sum of the 2-norm of its rows, so I use the function `sum()` but it doesn't work as I expect it to do here an example

```
# The matrix F
> F <- matrix(c(9,1,1,1,4,1),nrow=3)
# index of the sum i
> i=1:NROW(F)
#And here is the result 
> sum(norm(F[i,], type = "2")^4)
  [1] 7376.60160040254
# and if i calculate each element of the sum i get
> norm(F[1,], type = "2")^4
  [1] 6724
> norm(F[2,], type = "2")^4
  [1] 289
> norm(F[3,], type = "2")^4
  [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `apply` function. It applies a function along the dimensions of a matrix.

```
sum(apply(F,MARGIN = 1,function(x){norm(x,type = "2")^4}))
#[1] 7017
```

The reason yours doesn't work is because you assigned `c(1,2,3)` to `i`. Then, when you subset `F`, you just get the whole matrix.

```
i=1:NROW(F)
i
#[1] 1 2 3
norm(F,type="2")^4
#[1] 7376.602
norm(F[1:3,],type="2")^4
#[1] 7376.602
norm(F[i,],type="2")^4
#[1] 7376.602
```

Disclaimer: I have not assessed the mathematical validity of this approach, only programmatically recreated the OP's desired behavior.

Comment: yeah i did it but i just want to understand whats happening exactly

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Let me know if that still isn't clear.